# POST request made with CSRF token through multipart form is giving 404 error on production but working on localhost

Tags: express, deployment, csrf, multipartform-data

So the problem is, whenever I'm making a POST request through a multipart form, it's giving 404 error on production (aws ec2 with nginx as reverse proxy) but working fine on localhost.

My form looks like,

```
<form name="sell" method="POST" action="/item/sell/?_csrf=<%=locals.csrfToken%>" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" class="form" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the item name" required type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the item description" required type="text" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" name="price" min="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the item price" required> 
    </div>          
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

(and I have not included csrf hidden input in the form).

If I remove the enctype of multipart from the form, remove the file input, include hidden input for csrf token and make `action="/item/sell"`, then it's working fine even on production. This makes me certain that the 404 error is because of multipart encoding.

But I'm not able to figure out what is the reason behind it, I've tried removing nginx but that also doesn't seem to work.

The only thing that I found regarding multipart forms is that you need to include the csrf token in the `action` attr of the form instead of providing it as an input. I don't know what else could be done to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express does not natively support `multipart/formdata`. you can use modules like `multer` for this. You may have used the module `body-parser` when handling json body. Similarly you will need to use a module to handle multipart file uploads.

### Client/HTML

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

### Server/Express

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')

// destination folder to store the uploads
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Reference:
[How to handle multipart uploads in express](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear in the question but I am using multer and it is working as expected. But your code helped me realize that I didn't have uploads/ folder on the server and that's why I was getting 404. It was not about CSRF. Now the problem is solved now, thanks.